# How to emit data from NodeJS API call to Front-End with SocketsIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've made Electron app which uses [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) to communicate between back-end (NodeJS) and front-end (Jquery).

I've already sent data from

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => { socket.emit (.....) })
```

My problem is that I am not able to send data from API call.

Let me tell you the example.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.set('socketIo', io);

app.get('/api/run', (req, res) => {
    const ioEmitter = req.app.get("socketIo");
    ioEmitter.emit('data', 'some data'); // not working
    // ioEmitter.to(~some socket id~).emit('data', 'some-data')
    // not working either. I can't get anything to client side
})
```

Client side code

```js
socket.on('data', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg)
})
```

It's mandatory for me (the project) to get that data from API call.

Comment: Are you sure that the socket client is connected? You can add `io.on('connection', <callback-function>)` to verfiy that.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% aware about that. As I have mentioned in the post (on the 3rd line)

Comment: What if you don't use `io` as middleware (omitting `app.set('socketIo', io);) and call `io.emit('data', 'some data');` in your GET handler?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when I stop using `io` as a middleware and start using it directly, still nothing is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use io.emit instead of ioEmitter.emit as its defined in the global scope.